# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, expo

I want to implement a code to retrieve data from firestore collection

I use typescript as a programming language. But found an error while following the existing example, while the example uses javascript

the error occured at `setBookmark(querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {`

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const getBookmark = async () => {
      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "bookmark"));
        setBookmark(querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data()
          // console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
        }));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error getting document: ", e);
      }
    };

    getBookmark();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

forEach returns void hence the error. I think you want to use `.map` instead. Your current would always set `setBookmark(null)`. I would write the code for you but its not clear what goes into bookmark.

map will return a new list based on the old list while forEach is to just iterate and not returning anything.

Comment: How about using `.map` in my code?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, you can't use map with querySnapshot, but you can create an array from it.

```
const myArray = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  myArray.push({
    id: doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
  })
setBookmark(myArray)
```

Comment: What if I want to display the result using your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? If you want to show bookmarks on a page, you can do something like <ul>{bookmarks.map({id, data}) => <li key={id}>{data}</li>}</ul>

Comment: I got an error near **myArray = []**, said `Variable 'myArray' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.`

Comment: So, describe type like const myArray: {id: any, data: any}[] = []; Instead of `any`, put the real types of data and id.